# How can i pipeline find output into gdal_translate?

Tags: image, bash, find

how can i put the output of "find" into "gdal_translate" in bash? 
I need to translate a .tif image into .ers

Answer (score 1):

seems like you need -exec

```
find .  -name "*.tif" -exec sh -c 'gdal_translate "$1" "${1%.tif}.ers"' _ {} \;
```